# Where do I ask questions related to my technology stack for a web application?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need to ask a question related to the approaches and apt technology stack architecture for my web application. Think of it like a code review for my architecture diagram. But, I am not sure whether it is a question for Server Fault or Code Review or Super User.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar this question is a _very_ poor fit for Software Engineering - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: I don't read in the question that this is a shopping request, but a architectural question. I think the duplicate doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2):

It might be on-topic on Software Engineering. They [specifically allow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions about architecture and software design principals. You have to comply to their [strict rules about this subject](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6504/113279), so make sure you meet those before asking.

If your question is asking for tools to use, you might find some help on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but I am not familiar to the site, so make sure to read up well there.

Comment: [no,  Software Engineering is a poor fit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290570/where-do-i-ask-questions-related-to-my-technology-stack-for-a-web-application#comment943373_290570) for technology shopping. Wrt design, only questions that meet specific requirements may be OK, see eg [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6504/31260)

Comment: @gnat Updated. Hope it is okay now. I never said that shopping questions are okay there btw